# How to avoid mute microphone when the screen got locked in a PWA in angular for voice calling

Tags: angular, typescript, progressive-web-apps, agora.io

I implemented a PWA in Angular with agora.io voice calling and everything works fine but when the phone got locked the microphone got muted both ios and android. Then when I unlock the phone the microphone is still mute and I have to close and open the voice call again to keep speaking.
The audio works fine when the phone is locked by the way.

I'd rather not to use the foreground but if it's the only option I will do it even tough if the phone got locked manually the problem persits.

Answer (score 0):

That's a privacy issue, you can't access the microphone on locked phones (on the web platform at least).